# Alternative to INotifyPropertyChanged for UI Updates

Tags: c#, user-interface, c#-4.0, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to create a system where the user interface is not updated EVERY time a property of one of my business objects is changed, but instead is only updated in a controlled manner.

This is my reasoning:

1. The business objects are updated many hundreds of times per second, but it seems to me that the user really only needs to see an update every 250 or so milliseconds.  I was thinking about having a timer that elapses every 250 milliseconds and every time it elapses to call a method which would tell the UI that it needs to refresh itself.
2. The UI is fairly large and I wanted to make it so that the only control that would be refreshing themselves would be the ones that are currently being viewed by the user.

I am aware of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` model but wouldn't this unnecessarily update the UI every time anything was updated?

I tried using `.RefreshDataSource()`, but I was wondering if there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am aware of the INotifyPropertyChanged model but wouldn't this unnecessarily update the UI every time anything was updated?

Well, just if you call `NotifyPropertyChanged("PropertyName")` in the setter of the property, which is shown on the UI. Because this actually forces the UI to update **everytime** the property is set again - means many hundreds of times per second per property. You could also call `NotifyPropertyChanged("PropertyName")` in the method, which gets called everytime your timer elapses. So there's no need of using `RefreshDataSource()` instead of `INotifyPropertyChagend`.

Comment: I think that this is what I'll do - what happens if I were to call "NotifyPropertyChanged()" (without passing in the name of the property?  When I did a test, it seems to still work - if the string that you pass doesn't match any of the properties, does it update all of them?

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx): *The PropertyChanged event can indicate all properties on the object have changed by using either Nothing or String.Empty as the property name in the PropertyChangedEventArgs.*

This is what gets called in your `NotifyPropertyChanged` method. Common practice is to raise this event in each setter of each property. I do not know why, because firstly this event gets raised just once and secondly you're able to just use the {get;set;} syntax, which means less code.

Comment: I meant the event just gets raised once if you call the method with `String.empty`. It depends. If you just update your whole UI with one certain action, passing string.Empty might be better.
I think putting the `NotifyPropertyChanged` method in every is better if you don't want to update your whole UI when just one property gets modified.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose when NotifyPropertyChange is called - why not make a base class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged by suppressing frequent calls?